# Page break doesn't work while converting html to canvas and then to Pdf

Tags: html, css, reactjs, canvas, jspdf

I am converting HTML to the canvas and then to pdf by using jspdf it works great even for Arabic fonts but the only issue is if the data is exceeded, it just doesn't show so how to break the page and show the data on the new page.

[image]

Code:

```
img.src = dataUrl
document.getElementById('printAll').style.visibility = 'visible'   
const input = document.getElementById('printAll');
html2canvas(input)
.then((canvas) => {
  const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  document.getElementById('printAll').style.visibility = 'hidden'
  const pdf = new jsPDF();
  pdf.addImage(this.state.img,'PNG',50,10,pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 100,pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 850);
  if (img.src)
  pdf.addImage(img.src, 'PNG', 80, 22, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 100, pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 400);
  // pdf.rect(20, 20, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 40, 
  pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 40, 'S');
  pdf.setTextColor(128,0,128);
  pdf.text("Date", 30, 25);
  pdf.text(this.state.date, 50, 25);
  pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 35, 90);
  pdf.text('end',30,290)
  pdf.save("download.pdf");  
});
```

and my HTML is

```
<div id="printAll">
{this.state.Orders
   ?
    <Table hover bordered striped responsive size="sm" id="table">
      <tbody>
        {this.state.Orders.length
          ?   this.state.Orders.map((item,ind)=>{
                 return(
                    <tr>
                      <td>{item.key}</td>
                      <td>{item.value}</td>
                    </tr>
                 );
            })
          : null}
      </tbody>
     </Table>
   :
   <div>No data</div>
   }
</div>
```

I am using css for A4 page with media query and it also doesn't help

```
#printAll {
    visibility: hidden;
    left: 20px;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    page-break-after: always;
}


/* avoid splitting element across pages */
#no-break {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}

#break {
    page-break-before: always;
    page-break-after: always;
}

/* style sheet for "A4" printing */
@media print and (width: 21cm) and (height: 29.7cm) {
    .page-break {
        page-break-after: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        clear: both;
    }

    #printAll {
        page-break-after: auto;
    }

    .page-break-before {
        page-break-before: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        clear: both;
    }

    @page {
        margin: 3cm;
    }


    .noprint {
        display: none;
    }

    @page {
        size: 297mm 210mm;
        /* landscape */
        /* you can also specify margins here: */
        margin: 25mm;
        margin-right: 45mm;
        /* for compatibility with both A4 and Letter */
    }

    #table {
        width: 100% !important;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 5.5rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Print media has a `page-break-after` CSS property. I think you need stg. like this.

Comment: @trkaplan I am already using. Check I edited the question

Comment: To improve your chance of getting an answer, provide a codesandbox.io link which reproduces your problem. This way someone would work on it and make sure he/she resolved your problem. You can fork and modify a current sandbox or create your own. React + html2canvas: https://codesandbox.io/s/ryj5k318n4  jsPDF + React: https://codesandbox.io/s/p58nvw746j